# Basic connection to sql server

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have read many tutorial and examples, but still can't connect to the sql server.

I'm using window authentication and this simple code (stripped down to highlight the connection part)

```
    SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Trusted_Connection=True;connection timeout=5");

    try
    {
    myConnection.Open();
    "connected"
    }
    catch(SqlException ex)
    {
    "Send curriculum to mcdonald" + ex.Message
    }
```

I've tried localhost\sqlexpress, computername\sqlexpress and a lot of other settings, the service are on, the database is there and reacheable from sql server management and so on.
It's the first time that I try to use sql server so probably I'm forgetting something fundamental, what must I check to be sure to make it work?

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Is TCP/IP enabled in your SQL Server Network Configuration?

Comment: You say that Sql Server Management Studio can connect. What is the Server Name content on login dialog of SSMS?

Comment: The error is not in english except for "Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 ". All that says other than this is that can't connect to the database and to check the configuration

Comment: on the sql management studio I connect with the windows authentication and the server name "computername\SQLEXPRESS"

Comment: Never mind i didn't read the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

```
SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost\\InstanceName;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Trusted_Connection=True;connection timeout=5");
```

OR

```
SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\InstanceName;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Trusted_Connection=True;connection timeout=5");
```

OR

```
SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=ServerName\\InstanceName;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Trusted_Connection=True;connection timeout=5");
```

After reading you comments try this..

```
SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Trusted_Connection=True;connection timeout=5");
```

Comment: I've tried that too, the verbatim was a remnant just to autoescape the \